# get user data API not working flutter integration

Tags: flutter

below image showing my API for getting user data. it is working successfully. now I want it to connect to my flutter code to display the profile picture and username on the app bar. I have created **getdata()** method to connect API. but it is not working. how should I correct this and display on app bar.

[image: ![enter image description here]

```
class Dashboard extends StatefulWidget {
  const Dashboard({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Dashboard> createState() => _DashboardState();
}

class _DashboardState extends State<Dashboard> {
  bool dashoard = true;
  bool isLoading = true;

  String profilePicture = '';
  String username = '';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loading();

  }

  loading() async {
    await getdata();

  }

  getdata() async {
    var response;
    try {
      response = await Dio()
          .get(BASE_API + "user/getUserById/" + loginUserData["id"]!);

      print("response: $response");
      Map<String, dynamic> responseJson = json.decode(response.toString());

      setState(() {
        profilePicture = responseJson['data']['image'];
        username = responseJson['data']['userName'];
      });
      // print(responseJson['data']['userName']);

    } catch (e) {
      print(e);

    }
  }

Widget appbar() {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
            
           
              Image.asset(
                "assets/images/userimage.png",
                scale: 1,
              ),
           

            ],
          ),

           Row(
             children: [
              Text(
                username,
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white, fontSize:12),
              ),
             ],
           )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Please share reproducible code with api data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try out this**

**List<Map<String, dynamic>>? responseJson;**

**var response;**

```html
try {
          response = await Dio().get(BASE_API + "user/getUserById/" +loginUserData["id"]!);

          print("response: $response");
              response = json.decode(response.toString());


     for(var items in response){
          responseJson!.add(items);
        }


          setState(() {
            //profilePicture = responseJson['data']['image'];
            //username = responseJson['data']['userName'];
            profilePic = responseJson[0]["image"]; // new line added
          });
          // print(responseJson['data']['userName']);

        } catch (e) {
          print(e);

        }
```

Comment: kindly can you share the full code with try-catch? I'm struggling to place the code.

Comment: CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 18,
                  child: Image.network(profilePicture)),   <<< I add this on my app bar to display user image. but im getting Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:///

Comment: @Nidew Print your url and check it on browser.